# React Redux combineReducer | Reducer not being passed

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

My app has been using redux since the beginning, but only with one reducer. The cart reducer. Now I want to add another reducer and according to the redux docs, combineReducer is the way to go.

Now I've read trough the docs and looked trough the examples and tried implementing combineReducer to my apps store.

**What I expected to happen:**

Both reducers can be called individually whenever needed.

**What happend:**

Neither reducer works whenever using combineReducer, but each reducer works individual whenever but in the store.

Works:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartItems from '../reducers/cartItems';
import getPayment from '../reducers/getPayment';

export default store = createStore(cartItems)
```

Doesn't work:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartItems from '../reducers/cartItems';
import getPayment from '../reducers/getPayment';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cartItems,
    getPayment,
  });

export default store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

**Store -> Index.JS**

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartItems from '../reducers/cartItems';
import getPayment from '../reducers/getPayment';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cartItems,
    getPayment,
      });

export default store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

**Reducer -> cartItems.JS**

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        console.log('CarItems.JS', action.payload)
            if (state.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
                // increase qty if item already exists in cart
                return state.map(cartItem => (
                    cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 } : cartItem

                    ));

            }
            return [...state, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]; // else add the new item to cart

        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state
                .map(cartItem => (cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 } : cartItem))
                .filter(cartItem => cartItem.qty > 0);
    }
    return state
} 

export default cartItems
```

**App.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppNavigator />
        </Provider> 
        ) 
    }
}
```

**CartScreen**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  TouchableOpacity, 
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { addItemToCart, removeItem } from '../actions/ProductActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    state.map((item) => { // eslint-disable-line
      totalPrice += item.price * item.qty;
    });
    return {
        cartItems: state,
        totalPrice : totalPrice
    }
}
export class CartScreen extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    renderProducts = (products) => {
        return (
            <View key={products.index} style={styles.products}>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}> 
                    <Icon name={products.item.icon} color="#DD016B" size={25} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.text}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>
                        {products.item.name} 
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.price}>
                    € {products.item.price * products.item.qty}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => this.props.removeItem(products.item)} > 
                        <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-remove" color="white" size={25} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.qty}>{products.item.qty}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => this.props.addItemToCart(products.item)} > 
                        <Icon style={styles.button} name="ios-add" color="white" size={25} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Uw bestelling</Text>
                {console.log('CS', this.props.cartItems )}
                { 
                    this.props.cartItems.length>0?
                    <View>
                        <View style={styles.productContainer}>

                        <FlatList
                        style={styles.listContainer}
                        data={this.props.cartItems}
                        renderItem={this.renderProducts}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.total}>Totaal: € {this.props.totalPrice} </Text>    
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.checkOutContainer}  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Payment')}>  
                                <Icon style={styles.checkOutButton} name="ios-checkmark" color="white" size={35} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    : 
                    <Text style={styles.emptyContainer}>No Items in your cart</Text>
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps =  {
    addItemToCart,
    removeItem
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartScreen);
```

**CartIcon**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform
} from "react-native";

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const ShoppingCartIcon = (props) => (
    <View style={[{ padding: 5 }, Platform.OS == 'android' ? styles.iconContainer : null]}>
    <View style={{
        position: 'absolute', height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: '#DD016B', right: 15, bottom: 15, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', zIndex: 2000,

    }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{props.cartItems.length}</Text>
    </View>
    <Icon onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Cart')} name="ios-cart" color="white" size={30} />
</View>
) 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {cartItems, getPayment} = state;
    return {
        cartItems: state
    }
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withNavigation(ShoppingCartIcon));

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    iconContainer: {
        paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 10, marginRight: 5
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to access your redux state? Your `mapStateToProps` function in your components

Comment: Hi, I've added the cartscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `combineReducer`, you need to access your redux state in a different way. Your `cartItems` and `getPayment` state can be accessed in your `mapStateToProps` by using `state.cartItems` and `state.getPayment` respectively. Here is a way you can update your `mapStateToProps` function.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {cartItems, getPayment} = state;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    cartItems.map((item) => { // eslint-disable-line
      totalPrice += item.price * item.qty;
    });
    return {
        cartItems: cartItems,
        totalPrice : totalPrice
    }
}
```

## Update

For `CartIcon`, you can use it this way

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        cartItems: state.cartItems
    }
}
```

To explain, lets say if this is your current `cartItems` state, which you exported from `Reducer -> cartItems.JS`

```js
{
  itemOne: {
    price: '$10',
    qty: 20
  },
  itemOne: {
    price: '$10',
    qty: 20
  },
}
```

When you use `combineReducers`, the `state` you get in your `mapStateToProps` function will be like this. You can do a `console.log(state)` to check

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  /** this console.log will prints something like this
      state: {
        cartItems: {
          itemOne: {
            price: '$10',
            qty: 20
          },
          itemOne: {
            price: '$10',
            qty: 20
          },
        }
      },
      getPayment: {
        //your getPayment states
      }
  **/
  return {
    cartItems: state.cartItems
  }
}
```

Thats why to access your cart items, you need to do `state.cartItems`

Comment: It seems this doesn't solve it. I've added my cartIcon component, where I tried to apply this. Could you explain to me what's going?

Comment: Wicky, Thanks helped. Didn't find this mentioned on the docs.